# Pfaffian for Weyl Symbol approach to path integrals

Tags: path-integral, fermions, grassmann-numbers

In M. Henneaux and C. Teitelboim, Quantization of Gauge Systems. Princeton University Press, 1992. the authors claim that integrating the $\xi$'s out of this expression for the Weyl symbol of the time evolution operator
$$U(\xi_{N+1}, T)=(\epsilon_n\det\eta_{AB})^N(i/2)^{nN}\int\exp\left(\sum_{\nu=1}^N-2(\xi_\nu\cdot\eta_\nu+\eta_\nu\cdot\xi_{\nu+1}+\xi_{\nu+1}\cdot\xi_\nu)-iH(\eta_\nu)T/N)\right)\prod_{\nu=1}^N(d^n\eta_\nu   d^n\xi_\nu),$$
yields a Pfaffian
$$(-2i)^{nN/2}(\epsilon_n\det\eta)^{N/2}.$$
In here $\eta_{AB}$ is a diagonal matrix with entries $\pm1$, we have Grassmann variables $\eta_\nu^A$ and $\xi_\nu^A$, $\theta_1\cdot\theta_2:=\theta_1^A\eta_{AB}\theta_2^B$, and $\epsilon_n=1$ for even $n$ and $-i$ for odd $n$.

The Pfaffian should be obtained by computing something proportional to
$$\int\exp\left(\sum_{\nu=1}^{N-1}-2\xi_{\nu+1}\cdot\xi_\nu\right)\prod_{\nu=1}^Nd^n\xi_\nu,$$
There could be a factor of $(-1)^n$ depending on how you reorder the integrations. In any case, this determinant does yield a Pfaffian that has to be a square root of the determinant of the quadratic form
$$2\begin{bmatrix}0 & \eta & 0 & 0\\
-\eta & 0 & \eta & 0\\
0 & -\eta & 0 & \eta\\
\cdots\end{bmatrix}$$
Thus, the determinant of this form has to be $2^{nN}(\det\eta)^N$. Here is my first problem, since I don't see how to show this determinant since the matrix is not block diagonal.

My second problem then lies on computing the correct sign of the Pfaffian $(-i)^{nN/2}\epsilon_n^{N/2}$. Does one need to compute the normal form of the quadratic form?

Comment: Which page? Which eq?

Comment: Good point, sorry. It is equation (15.73) in page 359. This is in section 15.4, path integrals for fermions.